# How to fix line formats when reading a file

Tags: php, regex

How would I fix lines like the last one to make them look like the first two with regex?

```
"XY30-0601" "LMF II Trump"  7
"ZR3-0003601"   "Durable canvas"    3

"GQ450-020061"  "DMZ Power
Epic
Durable canvas
Handle for easy transport
Sturdy buttons to keep the case rolled up
Reinforced case stitching
"   17
```

I'm expecting

```
"XY30-0601" "LMF II Trump"  7
"ZR3-0003601"   "Durable canvas"    3
"GQ450-020061"  "DMZ Power Epic Durable canvas Handle for easy transport Sturdy buttons to keep the case rolled up Reinforced case stitching"   17
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj most likely the third item would be a one-liner like the first two

Comment: could you show trying code?

Comment: @AvinashRaj sure man no prob great answer +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try the below regex and replace the matched newline characters with a space.

```
\n(?:(?!")|(?=" +\d+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jZ2bH6/6)

**Code:**

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
"XY30-0601" "LMF II Trump"  7
"ZR3-0003601"   "Durable canvas"    3

"GQ450-020061"  "DMZ Power
Epic
Durable canvas
Handle for easy transport
Sturdy buttons to keep the case rolled up
Reinforced case stitching
"   17
EOT;
$pattern = '~\n(?:(?!")|(?=" +\d+))~';
$replacement = " ";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
"XY30-0601" "LMF II Trump"  7
"ZR3-0003601"   "Durable canvas"    3
"GQ450-020061"  "DMZ Power Epic Durable canvas Handle for easy transport Sturdy buttons to keep the case rolled up Reinforced case stitching "   17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=[^"]*")\n
```

You can use this.replace by a `space`.It uses a postive lookahead to find `\n` before `"`

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/14